# No option for free dyno?

Tags: heroku, dyno

[image]

I just joined someones heroku app as a collaborator and all we need is 1000 hours a month. So he added his cc but now I cannot select a free dyno. If i turn on a dyno it says $7 rather than 0. How can I downgrade to free dynos again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams#pricing-and-limits)

> Free dynos, which are available for personal apps, are not available to Teams.
> Create your own applications and use them for free, but cannot share this with anyone else.